# SQL Server - Querying using multiple WHERE statements on the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am attempting to create a single query that will output the purchases of customers in three time periods. The first will be 10/01/2010 through 09/31/2011, the second will be 10/01/2011 through 09/31/2012, etc.

The following queries return the data that I want, but I would like the purchases for each date period to be in a separate column in the same output. I could place the results from each query into Excel and perform a VLOOKUP on CUST_NO to merge the data, but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution.

2010 Query:

```
SELECT     STR_ID, CUST_NO, SUM(TOT) AS Expr2010
FROM       PS_TKT_HIST
WHERE      (BUS_DAT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-10-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-09-31 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY STR_ID, CUST_NO
```

2011 Query

```
SELECT     STR_ID, CUST_NO, SUM(TOT) AS Expr2011
FROM       PS_TKT_HIST
WHERE      (BUS_DAT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-10-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-09-31 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY STR_ID, CUST_NO
```

This gives me two separate results.

How can I combine WHERE clauses in the two queries into a single query that generates the results into a single set with separate columns (Expr2010, Expr2011, etc)?

Comment: The queries you posted do not produce two separate results. They're the same exact result, just given a different column alias for the SUMmed column. I think you made a mistake in the SQL you posted, or you've made a mistake in the where statement. (They both contain the same exxact datetime values in the WHERE, so they will return the same values.)

Comment: What you're looking to do is called a `Pivot`.  If you Google that, or look for examples here, that should get you started. If you know you only have 3 static date ranges, you could also use a `CASE WHEN` in three separate columns which would `SUM` the values that meet the criteria.

Comment: @KenWhite corrected the second query, thank you.

Comment: @Adamwenger Thank you Adam, I saw through research that CASE might be the solution, but couldn't find a good example that fit my particular situation. Will look into further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this the best idea to solve your problem. But  just providing you the idea that you can do like this..

```
SELECT     STR_ID, CUST_NO, 
(SELECT    SUM(TOT) AS Expr2010
FROM       PS_TKT_HIST
WHERE      (BUS_DAT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-10-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-09-31 00:00:00', 102))
) As Expr2010,
(
SELECT     SUM(TOT) AS Expr2011
FROM       PS_TKT_HIST
WHERE      (BUS_DAT BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-10-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-09-31 00:00:00', 102))
) As Expr2011
from PS_TKT_HIST
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Here is the result: `STR_ID     CUST_NO                                                 
---------- --------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1          2566036347      7753762.09                              7753762.09
10         7065702615      7753762.09                              7753762.09
7          2514636378      7753762.09                              7753762.09
1          8623527         7753762.09                              7753762.09
13         3345148707      7753762.09`

Comment: @TylerSmelley: You can set the alias.